# Prisma specific one to many relation

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I am a newbie with Prisma and would like to see how would prisma user do such a call.

I have the following models:

```
model ChallengeScore {
  id          Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  user       User @relation(fields: [username], references: [username])
  username     String
  challenge Challenge @relation(fields: [challengeAddress], references: [address])
  challengeAddress String
  isGasScore Boolean
  isByteScore Boolean
  score       Int
}

model Challenge {
  address String @unique
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  description String
  title String
  challengeScores ChallengeScore[]
}
```

What I want is fetch the challengeScores of a specific user for specific address where isGasScore is true and where score is the lowest. I want to do the same thing for isByteScore is true and score is the lowest.
I also want to fetch for the same specific address the 5 lowest scores (for any users) where isByteScore is true and where is isGasScore is true.

Is it doable in one call? If so what would it look like?

Also what is best practice, should I just fetch all the challengeScores and then filter it out the way I want on the front-end? I am guessing the first option is more costy db wise?

Any advice is appreciated !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a single transaction, or `Promise.all()` works too

```js
const username = 'U1';
const challengeAddress = 'C1';

const [lowestGas, lowestByte, lowestFive] = await prisma.$transaction([
    prisma.challengeScore.findFirst({
        where: { username, challengeAddress, isGasScore: true },
        orderBy: { score: 'asc' },
    }),
    prisma.challengeScore.findFirst({
        where: { username, challengeAddress, isByteScore: true },
        orderBy: { score: 'asc' },
    }),
    prisma.challengeScore.findMany({
        where: {
            username,
            challengeAddress,
            isGasScore: true,
            isByteScore: true,
        },
        orderBy: { score: 'asc' },
        take: 5,
    }),
]);
```

Whether to do filtering on frontend / backend / query differs for each implementation, and depends on the amount of data, filter complexity, reusability, data security etc.
If it is a small application it should be okay to filter in the frontend, but it wouldn't scale well in large applications.